# Which way does current flow in coronal loops and filaments?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, sun

My understanding is this: the Solar surface becomes speckled with more sunspots near Solar maximum, and these spots tend to form groupings known as active regions; each spot is associated with a given magnetic polarity, and often regions will tend to have spots of both polarities that are typically linked in certain ways, but sometimes the formed regions are much more complex, especially as the polar fields are about to flip and Solar activity tends to increase.

Now, my question is this, as the title says: which way does current flow in the plasma streams that form the coronal loops and filaments that are generally "rooted" in the active regions? Is there a way to determine the direction of current solely from the magnetic polarities of the spots involved, or can current flow in either direction?

Comment: Why does there need to be any current (in the loops)?

Comment: The direction of current flow is determined by the electrostatic potential that accelerates the charges. If we add a magnetic field to that, then the charge carriers will, in addition, gyrate around the magnetic field lines. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @ProfRob: You're right, there doesn't need to be, but with all of that plasma moving back and forth I would expect there to generally be some current present in either direction.

Comment: @FlatterMann: Not quite. I believe I understand what you mean, but my question is ultimately more like this: is there some connection between the underlying magnetic polarity and what those electrostatic fields are, so that current will tend to or always move in a given direction from a certain polarity to another? If there is any current at all, that is, as pointed out above.

Comment: There are, most likely, net currents, because there are temperature differences. This will cause, at the very least, a thermo-current, but I don't have a good feeling for the order of magnitude of these currents. Plasma has amazing conductivity, so even for tiny potential differences very large currents could be building up.